# Nifty-GUI text not rendering

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl, nifty-gui

I am trying to create a simple start screen for a game and I  am using LWJGL with nifty-gui.

Here is my existing code :

```
public class Main { 

public Main(){
     if (!LwjglInitHelper.initSubSystems("Risk It")) {
          System.exit(0);
        }
     Nifty nifty = new Nifty(
                new LwjglRenderDevice(),
                new OpenALSoundDevice(),
                new LwjglInputSystem(),
                new AccurateTimeProvider());
     Game game = new Game(nifty);
}


    public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {
       Main main = new Main();
    }

}

public class Game {

    public Game(Nifty nifty){
        nifty.fromXml("util/tutorial.xml", "start");
        LwjglInitHelper.renderLoop(nifty, null);
        LwjglInitHelper.destroy();
    }

}
```

The *LwjglInitHelper* class can be found [here](https://github.com/void256/nifty-gui/blob/0963b5f362c81594f6b364184ffe1052381b6984/nifty-html/src/test/java/example/LwjglInitHelper.java)

And my XML is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<nifty>
   <useStyles filename="nifty-default-styles.xml" />
   <useControls filename="nifty-default-controls.xml" />
   <screen id="start">
      <layer id="background" childLayout="center">
         <image filename="util/img/menuTexture.png" />
            <text text="My Cool Game" font="Venus_Rising.fnt" width="100%" height="100%" />
      </layer>
   </screen>
</nifty>
```

The text is not appearing on the screen though :

[image]

The .fnt file and .png file are in my classpath, in the src folder.

Any idea what the problem would be?

Answer (score 0):

your font property path is the problem. it need full path to .fnt file for  example:

> font="Interface/Fonts/AdobeArabic.fnt"